# Eyes won't move even using with ARP

Tags: modeling, rigging, auto-rig-pro

I was doing a sims 2 render, following a tutorial that I saw on Youtube, note that it's my first time doing a sims 2 render and using blender at the same time. I am using Auto Rig Pro/ARP. The problem is that the model's eyes doesn't move whenever I rig the head. I have no idea what to do next, as I tried rewatching everything from the tute but still the eyes won't budge. :(

[here's the tute that i'm following recently.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKY2zqjkCzg&ab_channel=BruisedPixels) I am using Blender 2.8, as reccomended in their video.
[Model's blenderfiles. The facerigs one is the most updated while the gonerilmybeloved file is the backup one before I added some rigs](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/h0jjmj67fl7c4/Goneril+Capp-BLENDER+FILES)
[image]

Comment: IDK about the tutorial, but do you understand how armatures and rigging fundamentally work? Like, vertex groups and the Armature Deform modifier and all that? (Also, I’m pretty sure NOBODY calls it a “tute” )

Answer (score 1):

The body has the Armature Modifier to control the mesh, but the eyes object does not.

[image: Armature Modifier]

To solve this select the eyes object first then the armature object, press Ctrl+P and select "With Automatic Weights".

[image: Automatic Weights]

This adds the Armature Modifer to the eyes object, set the object's parent to the Armature object and the adds weigths to the vertices for each deformation bones.

[image: With Armature Modifier]